# Does a model need to be explicitly passed to a view if the model is strongly bound to the view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have an example from a project I'm working on in which a particular model is passed on to the view from the controller, like this:

```
result = View(stu)           //stu is an object of type Student
  //
//
return result;
```

In that particular view, at the top I have `@model Project.Models.Student` and I have textboxes which bind the information entered to the model. However, in another controller I have another method that has the following code:

```
//
//
result = View();

//
```

and the view for this has `@model.Project.Models.Login`, but I can still bind things to the model from this view just like in the other view (eg, I have something like:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.login_name, new { maxlength = "30" })
```

I didn't pass a model to the view like I did in the first method, and yet it seems to have the same functionality. If I am using `@model` at the top of the view, does that mean that it is not necessary to explicitly pass a model object as a parameter from the controller method?

Comment: Always pass your model that is populated from controller to view.

Comment: Keyword in above comment is "populated"  - aka "initialized" with some values (for display, default values, etc.).

Comment: In my first example, the model is not yet populated,, since that is the method that will call the view that will allow information to be passed to the model. Does that mean it is unnecessary for it to be sent? @EdSF

Comment: If you're not going to use any initialization, not really - you can look at the default `Index` Actions in the controller templates....

Comment: okay, so to be 100% clear. For a model to be strongly binded to the view, all that is needed is @ model at the top. The passing of the model to the view as a parameter like View(stu) is not what binds it, it is just if the object has already been populated and you would like to display it in the view or something? @EdSF

Comment: `Binding` means binding **data**. If you (only) declare a Model, it's _properties_ are available to the view  (you have no data to "bind" to some display/view) - just like in your post where you are just using a Model's properties to set `<input name='some_model_property'...` Hth...

Answer (score 0):

If you declare @model at the top of your cshtml page, then your page expect to get model of the type you have declared. Of course you can choose not to use a model in your page, and in this situation your declare is useless.
In addition you can declare a model, but don't send any object to the view.
If you send an object, it must be the same type as you declare in @model.

Comment: okay. in my second example, I didn't pass the model into the view but I still declared @ model at the top, and it allows me to bind submitted data into the model anyway. Why? @Kram

Comment: Html.TextBoxFor generate text box input with the name and value as your model that you have passed to the lambda. Even when your model is null or empty, the text box will be generated without any value. Another case is If you will try the following code, you will get an execption :> Html.TextBox("name"), Model.login_name..

Comment: I wouldn't call it "useless" - it helps ensure that when the form is submitted that the payload sent "fits" an expected Model. Not that you can't simply type `<input name="login_name...` either  :)